# Exception when trying Breeze.js example in version 1.0.1

Tags: breeze

I'm attempting to try out Breeze.js and have downloaded the latest nugget package for the MVC sample.

However, every time I try to save data an exception is thrown in the SaveChanges action in the BreezeSampleController of:

'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'entities'

The library looks great and I would like to make sure I have the most stable bits.

Comment: 1.0.1 is stable. I just tried with ASP.NET MVC 4 Empty Web Application template and worked fine ... on my machine :-). We'll need more info from you. Please describe every step you took: version of VS2012, which template, if it built w/o error. Shouldn't take long as there are few steps to take. Thx

Comment: Ok, I started with a fresh MVC4 Empty Web App, then I added the nugget project for the 1.0.1 sample.  The project updated with all dependencies and I then started the app.  The sample DB is created fine, I can see the sample Todo list, however, when I try to change an item and save I'm getting the same Json Exception.  I will be happy to send the project files over, please let me know.

Comment: No promises but you can zip it and send it to breeze at ideablade dot com (delete the packages, bin, and obj folders first!).  What was the stack trace by the way? Guessing line 35 of `ContextProvider.cs`

Comment: It turned out the problem was that the Newtonsoft.Json assembly was installed in the GAC by Telerik Test Studio.  As soon as I installed it the exception was no longer thrown.  Thanks for all the help and I look forward to playing with the bits.

Comment: For tracking purposes, I've copied your finding into the answer. When you have a moment, would you please "accept" it as the answer (click the checkmark on the left). Thx and hope you enjoy BreezeJS

Answer (score 1):

Quoting KS: "t turned out the problem was that the Newtonsoft.Json assembly was installed in the GAC by Telerik Test Studio. As soon as I installed it the exception was no longer thrown."

Comment: Do you mean "uninstalled it"?  If the problem was due to the installed library in the GAC, then I'm assuming you had to uninstall it to remove the problem.

Comment: BTW, I've verified this now.  I had the same exception and when I uninistalled Telerik Test, the exception was no longer thrown.