# HotTowel Template extention, problems using BreezeJs to save changes on database

Tags: angularjs, json.net, breeze, hottowel

recently I have started using the HotTowel AngularJs BreezeJs template provided by John Papa http://www.johnpapa.net/hot-towel-angular/.

I have run into an error I can't get my head around: getting data from the server works without problems but when i try to call saveChanges() i get the following error:

*"Message='Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'entities'"*

The closest possible answers I found for this problems are from :[Exception when trying Breeze.js example in version 1.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610061/exception-when-trying-breeze-js-example-in-version-1-0-1) , but I didn't find Telerik Studio's installed on my pc. I do have a lot of other Telerik products like Fiddle, JustCode and others. I do have Newtonsoft dll installed in the GAC. From what I understand that can cause errors when using BreezeJS and I was wondering what is the best way to handle these errors- do I desinstall the dll from the GAC, and so probably breaking the Telerik products that use it, or is there another way around it.

For the code itself, I am using the Entity Framework, creating a database on Windows Azure using Code First. I have set a repository, following the example of John Papa, and connecting it with the BreezeController. As I said earlier, all the getters work perfectly, but when I try to post something i get an error. Under you can find the full error message:

```
    Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException was unhandled by user code
    HResult=-2146233088
    Message='Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'entities'
    Source=Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    StackTrace:
    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
    at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site,T0      arg0)
   at Breeze.ContextProvider.ContextProvider.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle, TransactionSettings transactionSettings)
   at CC.Dal.StudentHubRepository.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) in c:\Users\Georgi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LearningAngular.web\CC.Dal\StudentHubRepository.cs:line 26
   at CC.Web.Controllers.BreezeController.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) in c:\Users\Georgi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LearningAngular.web\LearningAngular.web\Controllers\BreezeController.cs:line 27
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException:
```

Thanks in advance for any information you can provide. As a daily user of StackOverflow for couple of years now, this is the first question I actually post, hopefully it is formulated clearly enough.

**EDIT**: I did find a workaround by publishing my code everytime on windows azure and testing it from there. I still can't test localy and it seems it was indeed because of the Telerik installed Newtonsoft dll in the GAC. For now atleast my code works from the server, but any suggestions for a solution so I can test localy would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the Telerik installed version of Newtonsoft in your app is misaligned with what is expected from the latest VS2013 installs. This has happened a lot. VS2013 broke many installs and you could be behind on Telerik updates. I suggest that you talk to Telerik about the version of Newtonsoft that they are putting into the GAC ... if that actually is the problem.

FWIW, there should be no problem of this nature. The stack you're describing is known to work in Azure.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012 to run the SPA, the latest update facilitates that a lot. I think you are correct that the Newtonsoft lirabriers installed in the GAC make some type of error. When I upload the website code to Azure, it works perfectly.